# SearchKit - Can I change a text search to whole word?

Tags: searchkit

I have been experimenting with SearchKit - it has proved really useful. Thanks to everyone contributing.

One of my fields on the form is a search on the Display Name of an orgnisational contact:

[image]

All other search fields work really well, but the school name search will take any instance of a string of chars and return records containing that string.  We deal with schools, so if I search on *Mary*, this will also return records with *Primary* or *Maryland*.  Users tend to know the school they are after, but church schools in particular have a lot of *St Mary'*s etc.  This is of course just one example.  Capitalisation is not an issue, but hundreds of records are!

So, is there a 'whole word only' setting anywhere one can turn on and off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an option called 'Automatic Wildcard' under CiviCRM >> Administer >> Customise Data and screens >> Search Preferences. Turning that off may fix your problem? But this setting will apply across whole site

Comment: Hi Pradeep - I never knew that option was there! It works for our usecase, so thanks for the tip!

Comment: Can you mark this as answered(tick box), if the solution worked for you? so that it can help others in the community

Comment: Sorry Pradeep, all ticked, I upvoted but clearly forgot to tick...